# How to align right within equation array

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

Suppose I have something like the following:

```
    \begin{eqnarray*}
\mathrm{gcd}(x^3 + 6x^2 + 5x + 5, x^3 + 13x^2 + 6x + 3) &=& 102x^2 + 108x + 2 \ \mathrm{with} \ p = 109 \\
\mathrm{gcd}(x^3 + 2x^2 + 9x + 4, x^3 + 3x^2 + 7x + 9) &=& 1 \ \mathrm{with} \ p = 131 \\
\mathrm{gcd}(x^3 + 3x^2 + 9x + 12, x^3 + 6x^2 + 12x + 4) &=& 6x + 122 \ \mathrm{with} \ p = 157
\end{eqnarray*}
```

How do I align the statements at the end of each line (i.e. the "with p = ..." bit) to the right?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/eqnarray-vs-align

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 11):

Never ever use `eqnarray`!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\gcd(x^3 + 6x^2 + 5x + 5, x^3 + 13x^2 + 6x + 3) &= 102x^2 + 108x + 2 &&\text{with } p = 109 \\
\gcd(x^3 + 2x^2 + 9x + 4, x^3 + 3x^2 + 7x + 9) &= 1 &&\text{with } p = 131 \\
\gcd(x^3 + 3x^2 + 9x + 12, x^3 + 6x^2 + 12x + 4) &= 6x + 122 &&\text{with } p = 157
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

The `align` environment provided by `amsmath` (with the not numbered *-variant) provides for as many alignment points you want. The first column is right aligned, the second is left aligned, the third is right aligned and so on.

Notice that the `&` goes *before* the alignment point (usually a relation).

So we put the explanation text in the fourth column; the `rl` blocks are separated from one another by suitable space.

The `\text` command allows spaces in it (contrarywise to `\mathrm`). The `\gcd` operator is predefined in LaTeX.

Comment: Why not to use `eqnarray`? you may ask. So, they say "Avoid `eqnarray`" in many ways: [PracTeX Journal](http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/madsen/), [TeX Blog](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/maths/eqnarray-align-environment/), and [LaTeX Tips](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~hildebr/tex/displays.html).